# Check whether an employee is present on three consecutive days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `tbl_A` with the following schema:

[image: tbl_A Schema]

After insert, I have the following data in `tbl_A`:

[image: Available data]

Now the question is how to write a query for the following scenario:

- Put (1) in front of any employee who was present three days consecutively
- Put (0) in front of employee who was not present three days consecutively

The output screen shoot:

[image: output]

I think we should use case statement, but I am not able to check three consecutive days from date. I hope I am helped in this

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean literally 3 consecutive days, or 3 consecutive *working* days?

Comment: Yeah, I mean three consecutive working days

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, case when max(cons_days) >= 3 then 1 else 0 end as presence
from (
  select name, count(*) as cons_days
  from tbl_A, (values (0),(1),(2)) as a(dd)
  group by name, adate + dd
)x
group by name
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. Could you please explain how it works.

Comment: Every day taken three times - for today, for tomorrow and for the day after tomorrow. After grouping by date we get for each day the count of previous consecutive working days (including this). And then we just check if there are at least one day with the count greater or equal three.

Comment: Every day is taken three times- can be achieved using this statement: 

(values (0),(1),(2)) as a(dd)


?

Comment: Yes. By the way, I've replaced `dateadd` by `adate + dd` in my answer, `dateadd` was from sqlserver syntax.

Answer (score 0):

With a self-join on `name` and `available = 'Y'`, we create an inner table with  different combinations of dates for a given `name` and take a count of those entries in which the dates of the two instances of the table are less than 2 units apart i.e. for each value of a date `adate`, it will check for entries with its own value `adate` as well as `adate + 1` and `adate + 2`. If all 3 entries are present, the count will be `3` and you will have a flag with value `1` for such `names`(this is done in the outer query). Try the below query:

```
SELECT Z.NAME,
CASE WHEN Z.CONSEQ_AVAIL >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS YOUR_FLAG
FROM
    (
    SELECT A.NAME,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.ADATE >= A.ADATE AND B.ADATE <= A.ADATE + 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CONSEQ_AVAIL
    FROM 
    TABL_A A INNER JOIN TABL_A B
    ON A.NAME = B.NAME AND A.AVAILABLE = 'Y' AND B.AVAILABLE = 'Y'
    GROUP BY A.NAME
    ) Z;
```

Due to the complexity of the problem, I have not been able to test it out. If something is really wrong, please let me know and I will be happy to take down my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
--Below is My Approch

select Name,
       Case WHen Max_Count>=3 Then 1 else 0 end as Presence
from 
(
    Select Name,MAx(Coun) as Max_Count
    from 
  (
      select Name, (count(*) over (partition by Name,Ref_Date)) as Coun from
      (
        select  Name,adate + row_number()  over (partition by Name order by Adate  desc) as Ref_Date
        from temp
        where available='Y'
       )
  ) group by Name
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select name as employee , case when sum(diff) > =3 then 1 else 0 end as presence 
from 
(select id, name, Available,Adate, lead(Adate,1) over(order by name) as lead,
case when datediff(day, Adate,lead(Adate,1) over(order by name)) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as diff
from table_A
where Available = 'Y') A
group by name;
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.